# Build Redis & Redis-Stack from source in Electorn App

Tags: redis, electron, redis-stack

I'm working on an Electron app that uses Redis and Redis-stack as it's datastore. When I run it locally it works fine because I've already installed redis & redis-stack via homebrew. However when I package it up for production the users who download the app are missing required redis-stack dependencies (openssl).

Anyone know if there is there a way to install redis and redis-stack on application install without homebrew? It seems like I may also need to install openssl, but the app won't have permission to run brew install on the users behalf. Brew also requires Xcode tools, which seems like a non-starter if it needs to be installed too.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone ever runs into the same issue, I fixed this by building redis-stack directly from the [source](https://github.com/redis-stack/redis-stack?tab=readme-ov-file#building), not with homebrew.

Comment: this is not a solution, but a comment.